# Volume scatter has no shadow on clouds

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to make clouds. I watched "Clouds Tutorial for Blender Cycles - YouTube" but in render result, no shadow on clouds.

The sun strength is 16.000 and I also tried several different strengths and sizes.

Where is the problem?

[image]

Comment: You have a very bright background lighting the scene from all directions, thus making extremely flat lighting with no contrast possible. Bring down the background's strength so that you can evaluate your other lights better. In real life the clouds wold not be lit from the bottom (as the ground would absorb a lot of the light coming from the sun)

Answer (score 1):

Im going through same tutorial and have same issue. After couple hours I think I found solution. It has nothing to do with a light. U r using volume material for flat mesh, so the effect is strange. Just add another modifier - SOLIDIFY, and set thickness for about 5 or more. This way u will get simmilar effect as Andrew. I guess the diffrece is Andrew was using older blender version.